# How to externalize Firebase keys / Google Maps API Keys in a flutter project?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I would like to open source the app I am working on, but still use it personally. How would I externalize the firebase keys and google maps api keys so they aren't available in the public repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a directory inside `lib/` for private code that can go into a separate repo. For private data that is not code, use a top level directory.

Let's say private dirs are called `internal`. Here is an example tree.

```
project/
  lib/
    internal/  <-- separate repo.
    view/
    model/
    ...
  test/
  android/
  ios/
  ...
```

Make sure to add `internal/` to `.gitignore` in your main project. Then make another repo inside the private dir. This is sufficient if the private data doesn't change that often and you don't mind committing the changes separately. There are git managed ways to have nested repos, but it is too difficult for a situation like this imo.

Now just create a class in the `internal/` folder and import it from another file just as usual.

**internal/keys.dart**

```
final googleMapsKey = 'aj349aj4fp0_394jfam4gni-aoig4ja4goeifnwfa093';
// Firebase key, etc.
```

**view/map.dart**

```
import '../internal/keys.dart';
var googleMap = new GoogleMap(apiKey: googleMapsKey);
```

You get the idea.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How to handle the API key for Google maps that is registered in the AppDelegate file? [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR KEY"];

Comment: I'm not sure exactly. You could probably have a script insert the key where it's needed as part of the build/run process. But for Google Maps keys I believe you can restrict them in the API console so that it can only be used on iOS using your app for example.

Comment: I also believe the Firebase GoogleService-Info.plist, google-services.json are tied to a specific bundle-id so would not be useful outside an app signed with those specific keys (so, yes, store the keys elsewhere).  The Google Maps API is a different story - those may be useful outside a particular bundle-id ...

Comment: Couldn't someone just decompile and get it that way?